# Is it possible to limit the Editor.Log size Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory, logfile

Yesterday my hard disk suddenly said that there is no memory storage left. I have searched a little bit and found out that my Unity Editor.log file was 90GB big. I just deleted it and thats no problem but i wanted to know if there is a way in unity to set a maximum size for the logfile or if i have to delete it if its to big all the time.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. The best thing to do is simply not to use so many logs.

Comment: @LouisGarczynski the log file size rises automaticly when you have errors in code or use debug.Log. There must be a way to set a maximum size

Comment: As it should, just like any file that is constantly written to. Erasing data automatically would cause a lot more problems. You can create your own ILogHandler though, that works differently, but that's up to you.